# Link 2 Firebird databases with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Short summary. I have 2 databases (Invoices.gdb and Users.gdb)
I want to get a table where I can see which Invoice is linked to wich customer
For you info: I know the PHP code to get my values into the table. I'm struggling to get my LINK right between the 2 databases AND how I can execute this query.

My PDO class (only contains 1 connection right now)

```
class DatabasePDO{
    /** @var PDO */
    private static $dbh;

    static function getInstance(){
        $str_conn="firebird:host=localhost;dbname=C:/Users/Desktop/USERS.GDB;charset=UTF8";
        try{
            self::$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, "username", "password");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error!: ".$e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        return self::$dbh;
    }
```

That's only to get my users(and it works). How can I add my Invoices DB?

This is my class

```
public static function getInvoices() {
        $conn = DatabasePDO::getInstance();
        $sql = "select * from users.customers as A , invoices.invoice as B
                where a.customers.customerid = b.invoice.customerid";
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->execute();
        $list = array();
        while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
            $invoice= new invoice( $row );
            $list[] = $invoice;
        }
        $conn = null;
        return $list;
    }
```

The query I want to make is this the following:

```
select * from users.customers as A , invoices.invoice as B
where a.customers.customerid = b.invoice.customerid
```

I can't merge the 2 databases together. So that's no solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use Firebird or Interbase? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Firedbird, sorry.  Will change the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird databases are isolated and you can't join between databases. The best solution would be to merge your two databases into one (that would also have the added benefit of having integrity checks like foreign key constraints, etc).

The second best would be to have a **copy** of your *users* database (or at least the required tables) in your *invoices* database. You would then need to synchronize changes in *users* to *invoices* (eg using triggers and [`EXECUTE STATEMENT ON EXTERNAL`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt), or a scheduled to job to do the synchronization).

Otherwise you will have to do joining by hand in your code, and this is far from optimal.

Comment: I can't simply merge the 2 databases together because they were made for 2 seperate Programs (exe).
Could it be a solution to make a seperate mysql db, where I store all the needed data and get the data from there?

Comment: @Steve the fact they where created for different programs does not mean that you can't put the data in a single database. Also, how will moving things to MySQL make things simpler than just merging the databases, or copying/replicating the data into the other database.

Comment: It's possible. However both databases are getting updated daily. So got to find a solution to keep it up to date